# Regularity of metric under smooth map.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a map of regularity $C^{k, \alpha}(M)$, i.e. an element of the Hölder space for parameters $k$ and $\alpha$. Let $g$ be the pullback of the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$ under $f$. Can you tell me what type of Hölder regularity $g$ has, i.e. to which Hölder spaces it belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pullback metric is $$g_{ij} = \sum_k\frac{\partial f^k}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f^k}{\partial x^j}.$$ Since $f$ is $C^{k;\alpha}$ we know its partial derivatives are $C^{k-1;\alpha}$. Since Hoelder spaces are closed under addition and multiplication, we can conclude that $g$ is $C^{k-1;\alpha}$.